# How to remove a pattern in naming of keys of an array and returning it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Sample array:

```
array( 'keyword-one' => 'value', 'keyword-two' => 'value' );
```

What can I do so I get returned an array with **keyword-** omitted from the key so:

```
array( 'one' => 'value', 'two' => 'value' );
```

Comment: VTC as Too Broad?

Comment: I was waiting as there is a time limit before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` to replace in the keys from `array_keys()` and combine with the values using `array_combine()`:

```
$array = array_combine(str_replace('keyword-', '', array_keys($array)), $array);
```

For more complex patterns use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).